# Using GitHub on Mac OX 10.6.8: Repository is not updated online GitHub, but commit history is updated in RStudio

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8, and I recently downloaded Git 1.7.9.1 Snow Leopard Intel Universal. I am not sure if I set it up correctly. I do not have an icon for Git on my Desktop for local usage (which would be nice). However, if I type "git version" in command line, I get "git version 1.7.9.1".

I followed instructions for using RStudio with GitHub. Namely, in RStudio, I did Tools --> Global Options --> Git/SVN. My SSH RSA Key is set up, and my Git executable is /usr/local/git/bin/git, and my SVN executable is /usr/bin/svn. I also clicked "Enable version control interface for RStudio projects."

I have a repository downloaded from my GitHub online, and it has a .rmd file. In RStudio Git tab, I am able to open the .rmd file, add information to it, hit "Commit", and hit "Push" without any errors. When I close RStudio, and open it again, the .rmd file seems to be updated. And I can click on the "History" tab, and view my recent changes.

However, my changes are not updated on the online repository. Also, I can see other users' updates on the online repository .rmd file, but I cannot see their updates in my Rstudio .rmd file.

I realize questions like this are not uncommon online, but I am unable to find similar questions (same GitHub and Mac version) and same problems, whose answers I can understand.

One thing I am poor at, is making sure things are in the correct folders, and I worry that my Git repository files are incorrectly placed.

Comment: What is the result of "git remote -v", if you run it from command line

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It is "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: Sorry, when I actually ran the command you mentioned in the directory where the .rmd file is, I got the reply "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /directoryPathway/.git/"